# strcmp returns __strcmp_sse2_unaligned () in a simple string search programme

Tags: c, strcmp

I am currently fighting with a primitive search routine. It uses strcmp to compare a string given against a two dim array of strings.
GDP returns:

> "__strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:30 30      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory".

Edited: Trying to move on, added command line for string input procedure. Somehow, it is mistaken.

here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char dictionary()
{
   
    char **strings = (char**)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        //printf("%d\n", i);
        strings[i] = (char*)malloc(7*sizeof(char));
    }

    sprintf(strings[0], "mark");
    sprintf(strings[1], "ala");
    sprintf(strings[2], "wojtek");
    sprintf(strings[3], "tom");
    sprintf(strings[4], "john");
   
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Line #%d(length: %lu): %s\n", i, strlen(strings[i]),strings[i]);
    } 

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        free(strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);
}

int cmp(char *s1, char *s2[][10]){
    int i = 0;
    //size_t l = strlen(s1);
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            
            if (strcmp(s1, s2[i][7*sizeof(char)]) == 0)
            
            {
            
                printf("OK \n");
                            
                } else {
        
    printf("sth is wrong \n");  
            }
return 0;
    }
}

int main(){

    char BufText[255];
    int n=0;
    char sign;
    fflush(stdin);
    n = 0;
    do {
        sign = getchar();
        BufText[n ++] = sign;
        if(n >= 253) break;
    } while (sign !='\n');
    BufText [n] = 0;
    char **dict = dictionary();
    cmp(BufText, dict);
    free_dictionary(dict);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `dictionary` function does not return anything, while it's supposed to return a `char` (from it's prototype).

Comment: There's a lot of errors / flaws in your code, can you please explain exactly what it's supposed to do ? Does the `cmp` function needs to return something so you can use the result in the main?

Comment: You should enable warnings in your compiler. It should scream at you when you try to pass a function pointer as second parameter to `cmp` instead of an array.

Comment: What is this all expected to do? `strcmp(s1, s2[i][7*sizeof(char)])` is that supposed to access the array of pointers created in the other function? You only alloc 7 bytes per entry. There is no index 7.

Comment: yes, cmp function shall indicate, whether string from it's parameter is identical with one of dictionary contained strings. The cmp result is a part of UDP server response to a client (Separate code section not included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, there's a lot of flaws in your code.

First in your main, you're trying to `cmp("ala", dictionary);` but `dictionary` is an undeclared variable. I think you wanted to use the result of your `dictionary()`  call into the `cmp` call. So you need to store the `dictionary()` result into your `dictionary` variable. It can't actually be done because your `dictionary()` func does not return anything and free the allocated dict before it can be used.

I could continue this way but here's a patched version of your code. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char **dictionary()
{

    char **dict = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5);
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        dict[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);

    sprintf(dict[0], "mark");
    sprintf(dict[1], "ala");
    sprintf(dict[2], "wojtek");
    sprintf(dict[3], "tom");
    sprintf(dict[4], "john");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("Line #%d(length: %lu): %s\n", i, strlen(dict[i]),dict[i]);

    return (dict);
}

void free_dictionary(char **dict)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        free(dict[i]);
    free(dict);
}

void cmp(char *s1, char *s2[5])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s1, s2[i]) == 0)
            printf("OK \n");
        else
            printf("sth is wrong \n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **dict = dictionary();

    cmp("ala", dict);
    free_dictionary(dict);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You want the `cmp` function to compare a string with a string array. So it need to take your string and your array as arguments, s1 is your string, s2 your array. The expression `*s2[5]` means "take an array of 5 char pointers and name it s2." Each time you will access s2 with an index between 0 and 4, you will get one of your strings in the array.

Comment: In your code, you were asking to pass a char*** as argument (an array of array pointer)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help and comments. Now it is time for me again to do some progress.

Comment: You're welcome, please think to accept the answer to close your question